# how to make shorter conditional syntax using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two form fields one is category dropdown and another is product dropdown. Based on one condition, when it is true then category and product both will be dropdown. If that condition is false then category will be same dropdown but product will be auto complete search field

**Here i am getting the result by using broader and repetitive code approach like below**

```
if(dataSource) {
               newProductFields = {
                   category_name: {
                     ...productFields.category_name,
                     disabled: true
                  },
                   product_name: {
                     ...productFields.product_name,
                }
             };
           }
           else if(!dataSource) {
               newProductFields = {
                   category_name: {
                     ...productFields.category_name,
                     disabled: true
                  },
                   product_name: productField.product_name
             };
           }
```

I want to do this approach shorter then category_name will not be use multiple times for each condition

Comment: `else` is enough; you don't need to the check reverse condition. As for the rest, keep the object outside the condition and only change `product_name`.

Comment: Is `productFields` vs `productField` a typo?

Comment: Why are you using spread syntax for `{ ...productFields.product_name, }`? Why not just `productFields.product_name`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the conditional operator in the `product_name` value instead:

```
newProductFields = {
    category_name: {
        ...productFields.category_name,
        disabled: true
    },
    product_name: dataSource
        ? { ...productFields.product_name }
        : productField.product_name
};
```